# Breakpoints in JRE System Library in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, debugging, breakpoints, java

I tried to make breakpoint in the class from JRE System Library, but when I started debug I recieved message: "Unable to install breakpoint at ... due to missing line number attributes. Modify compiler options to generate line number attributes."
So what should I do: recompile JRE System Library from sources with debug information and use it? Or there is some more simple way?

Comment: did you attach the source already?

Comment: Yes, I did. If I hadn't attached sources already I couldn't have made breakpoint in Eclipse.

Comment: as JRE do not include debug information, may be you can do the same with JDK ?

Comment: Thanks! It partly work - with JDK I can use breakpoints in system library.

Answer (score 1):

So, the most simple way - to use JDK instead of JRE. In this case we can use breakpoints in system library. BUT we cant monitor values of local variables. For this purpose we should recompile rt.jar (without sun.* packets, because they are proprietary). Process of recompilation described [there](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/java/97262/). It's in russian, but at the and of article situated the link to the result rt-dbg.jar.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to enable some compiler options. Right click your project and select `Properties`. Go to `Java Compiler` and enable the checkboxes `Add line number to generated class files (used by the debugger)` and the other ones.

Comment: It's set by default. But it is for my code. JRE System Library has been compiled already. Therefore I should recompile all JRE SL

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing to do is get the equivalent JDK and target that instead.